# How Do I Implement OAuth2 Authentication in a Node.js Express Application Using Passport?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

**I'm working on a Node.js Express application, and I want to implement OAuth2 authentication using Passport.js. Specifically, I'm looking to allow users to sign in with their Google accounts. **

I've already set up the basic Express application and installed Passport, but I'm not sure about the exact steps to integrate Google OAuth2.

Here's what I've done so far:
**1.** Installed the required npm packages (express, passport, passport-google-oauth20).
**2.** Created a Google Developer Console project and obtained the client ID and client secret.
**3.** Set up the Passport middleware with a local strategy for email/password login.

Now, I need guidance on how to configure Passport for Google OAuth2 authentication and how to handle user sessions once they are authenticated.

*If anyone could provide a step-by-step guide or point me to some code examples or tutorials, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!*

I followed the official documentation for setting up Google OAuth2 authentication with Passport.js for my Node.js Express application. I installed the required npm packages, created a Google Developer Console project, and obtained the client ID and client secret. I also configured the Passport middleware with a local strategy for email/password login, which is working as expected.

Expected Outcome:

I expected that, after implementing the Google OAuth2 strategy, when a user clicks on the "Sign in with Google" button on my website, they would be redirected to Google for authentication. Upon successful authentication, they would be redirected back to my site, and their user data would be stored in my database. Subsequently, they would be logged in and able to access protected routes.

Actual Result:

However, when I click on the "Sign in with Google" button, I'm redirected to Google for authentication, and that part works fine. But after I authenticate with Google, I'm not redirected back to my website as expected. Instead, I receive a "Cannot GET /auth/google/callback" error, and the user data is not saved to my database.

I've double-checked my code for any typos or configuration errors but haven't been able to identify the issue.

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to correctly configure Passport.js for Google OAuth2 authentication in my Node.js Express application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is telling you that your server, express app, isn't handling the `/auth/google/callback` path. You need to set that route up in your express app code.

Something like:

```
app.get("/auth/google/callback", async (req, res) => { ... } )
```

This is where they will be redirected after authenticating. The logic here will depend on the particular OAuth 2.0 flow you're using.